# Redirection from http to https (Pencilblue Elastic Beanstalk)

Tags: javascript, http, https, http-redirect, pencilblue

We're trying to redirect all the hits from `http` to `https`. Currently the application is deployed on elastic beanstalk and it's allowing both http and https, but we only want the `https`.

I've tried adding the **server object** in `config.js` to make the check

`pb.config.server.ssl.use_x_forwarded && req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] !== "https"`

work in `pencilblue.js`, but it broke the code on localhost as well as live.

Could you please suggest a way to redirect all `http` hits to `https`?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have countered this issue and got a solution, you can set `use_x_forwarded` to true in `config.js` file.

Comment: Thanks @wasif I have been stuck on this for quick sometime, but your answer resolved it.

Comment: Anytime, @tqr :)